# How do I join two tables in Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, join, orm

I am a beginner in Django and I know this question has alredy been asked, but I've tried every possible solution from previous answers and it still doesn't work. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The thing is my view currently returns all the fields of the Grade table, but I need it to return all of those fields plus the "name" field which is in the Student table, by joining the two tables.

I read that Django should do it automatically as long as I use ForeignKey, which I did, but it actually doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? I'm sorry if it's a noob question and if the solution is really obvious, I'm still trying to learn how Django works.

**app/models.py**

```
class Student(models.Model):
   id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, default=0)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Grade(models.Model):
   subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   grade = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**app/serializers.py**

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Student
      fields = ('id', 'name')

class GradeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Grade
      fields = ('subject', 'grade', 'student')
```

**app/views.py**

```
class StudentView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   serializer_class = StudentSerializer
   queryset = Student.objects.all()

class GradeView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   serializer_class = GradeSerializer
   queryset = Grade.objects.all().select_related("student")
   
   filterset_fields = ('student')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the student you can use the `StudentsSerializer, like:

```
class GradeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    student = StudentSerializer()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Grade
        fields = ('subject', 'grade', 'student')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried it and it worked!
I'll mark your answer as accepted in 8 minutes, it won't let me do it before that